# Problems with JScript upload plugin

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, file-upload

so i'm trying to upload mp3 and mp4 files into my server but it doesn't seem to be uploading. the plugin uploads every other format but mp3 and mp4, it shows it uploading the mp3 and mp4 format but when i check the server the files are not there as they were not uploaded. I am using the drpozone.js plugin. It is a bit lengthy so i can't type it below so i will put the link below.

Here is my Upload page (index.html):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if IE 8 ]><html class="no-js oldie ie8" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9 ]><html class="no-js oldie ie9" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if (gte IE 9)|!(IE)]><!--><html class="no-js" lang="en"> <!--<![endif]-->
<head>

   <!--- basic page needs
   ================================================== -->
   <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title>Samuel NewDay</title>
 <meta name="description" content="">  
 <meta name="author" content="">

   <!-- mobile specific metas
   ================================================== -->
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">

  <!-- CSS
   ================================================== -->
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/base.css">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/vendor.min.css">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/dropzone.css" />     

   <!-- script
   ================================================== -->
 <script src="js/modernizr.js"></script>
 <script src="js/dropzone.js"></script>

   <!-- favicons
 ================================================== -->
 <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.png" >

</head>

<body>

 <!-- header
   ================================================== -->
   <header id="main-header">

    <div class="row">

       <div class="logo">
          <a href="index.html">Samuel Newday</a>
       </div>

       <nav id="nav-wrap">         
          
          <a class="mobile-btn" href="#nav-wrap" title="Show navigation">
           <span class="menu-icon">Menu</span>
          </a>
          <a class="mobile-btn" href="#" title="Hide navigation">
           <span class="menu-icon">Menu</span>
          </a>            

          <ul id="nav" class="nav">
             <li><a class="smoothscroll" href="#eps">Upload Albums/EPs.</a></li>
           <li class="current"><a class="smoothscroll" href="#singles">Singles.</a></li>
             <li><a class="smoothscroll" href="##photos">Photoshoots.</a></li>
             <li><a class="smoothscroll" href="#events">Events.</a></li>
          </ul> <!-- end #nav -->

       </nav> <!-- end #nav-wrap -->

       <ul class="header-social">
          <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a></li>
          <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
          <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i></a></li>
       </ul>      

    </div>

   </header> <!-- end header -->
   <!-- homepage
   ================================================== -->
   <section id="top"> 
  <div class="row hero-content">
   <div class="twelve columns hero-container">
      <!-- hero-slider start-->
      <div id="hero-slider" class="flexslider">
       <ul class="slides">
        <!-- slide -->
        <li>
         <div class="flex-caption">
        <h1 class="">Admin Backend</h1>
        <h3 class="" style="color: white">Here you can upload <a class="smoothscroll" href="#eps" title="portfolio" >Albums/EPs</a>, <a class="smoothscroll" href="#singles" title="portfolio" >Singles</a>, <a class="smoothscroll" href="#photos" title="portfolio" >Photoshoots</a> and <a class="smoothscroll" href="#events" title="portfolio" >Upcoming Events!</a><br />You can also edit some of the website's information here!</h3>      
       </div>
        </li>                   
       </ul>
      </div> <!-- end hero-slider -->       
       </div> <!-- end twelve columns-->
  </div> <!-- end row --> 
  <div id="more">
        <a class="smoothscroll" href="#eps">Manage Site<i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i></a>
  </div>  
   </section> <!-- end homepage hero -->

     <!-- Album/EP Upload Section
   ================================================== -->
   <section id="Section1">
    <div class="row section-head">
       <div class="twelve columns">
        <h1>Upload Album/EP<span>.</span></h1>
          <hr />          
          <p>Upload Album/EP according to the steps below.</p>
       </div> <!-- end section-head -->
      </div>
      <div class="row mobile-no-padding">        
       <div class="process bgrid-half tab-bgrid-whole group">
        <div class="bgrid">
         <h3>Album/EP Artwok.</h3> 
         <p>
                      <div class="image_upload_div">
                          <form action="upload.php" class="dropzone">
                          </form>
                      </div>
         </p>
      </div>
        <div class="bgrid">
         <h3>Tracks.</h3>
         <p>
                     <div class="image_upload_div">
                          <form action="upload.php" class="dropzone">
                          </form>
                      </div>
         </p> 
        </div>
       </div> <!-- end process -->       
      </div> <!-- end row -->
   </section> <!-- end album/ep upload -->
   
   <!-- Footer
   ================================================== -->
   <footer>

      <div class="row">  

       <div class="twelve columns content group">
        
    <ul class="social-links">
               <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook-square"></i></a></li>
               <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter-square"></i></a></li>
               <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-google-plus-square"></i></a></li>               
               <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-youtube-play"></i></a></li>
               <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-vimeo-square"></i></a></li>
               <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-flickr"></i></a></li>               
               <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-skype"></i></a></li>
            </ul>

            <hr />

       </div>           

         <ul class="copyright">
          <li>&copy; Copyright 2017 Samuel NewDay.</li> 
         </ul>

         <div id="go-top">
            <a class="smoothscroll" title="Back to Top" href="#top">Back to Top<i class="fa fa-angle-up"></i></a>
         </div>

      </div> <!-- end row -->

   </footer> <!-- end footer -->

   <div id="preloader"> 
     <div id="loader"></div>
   </div> 

   <!-- Java Script
   ================================================== --> 
   <script src="js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
   <script src="js/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
   <script src="js/jquery.flexslider-min.js"></script>
   <script src="js/jquery.waypoints.min.js"></script>
   <script src="js/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
   <script src="js/jquery.fittext.js"></script>
   <script src="js/jquery.placeholder.min.js"></script>
   <script src="js/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js"></script>  
   <script src="js/main.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Here is the upload.php file:

```html
<?php
if(!empty($_FILES)){
 
 //database configuration
 $dbHost = 'localhost';
 $dbUsername = 'root';
 $dbPassword = '';
 $dbName = 'uploads';
 //connect with the database
 $conn = new mysqli($dbHost, $dbUsername, $dbPassword, $dbName);
 if($mysqli->connect_errno){
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $mysqli->connect_error;
 }
 
 $targetDir = "uploads/";
 $fileName = $_FILES['file']['name'];
 $targetFile = $targetDir.$fileName;
 if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'],$targetFile)){
  //insert file information into db table
  $conn->query("INSERT INTO files (file_name, uploaded) VALUES('".$fileName."','".date("Y-m-d H:i:s")."')");
 }
 
}
?>
```

The JScript file for Dropzone can be found at the below link:

[Dropzone Link](http://www.dropzonejs.com/)

Please let me know how i can make it to upload mp3 and mp4 formats. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you're uploading files you have to set the `enctype` of your `form` to `multipart/form-data` otherwise file uploads don't happen (iirc the filename gets sent as the value of the file). Take a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form for a good reference. The `enctype` attribute is talked about there.

Comment: I just tried that it still doesn't upload the files to the server. I've gone through the link but it doesn't help.

Comment: Hmm, looking at this I should have read the dropzone documentation. The enctype doesn't matter in this context, so apologies for misleading you. What is the response you are getting back when you try to upload a file?

Comment: when i upload a document (.png .jpg .jpeg .zip .gip) it loads then shows a tick that it has been uploaded to the server and when i check, i can find it in the server. but when i upload media (.mp3 .mp4 .avi .mkv) it shows it uploading then it shows a tick that the files have been uploaded to the server but when i check i can't find it in the server.